# For $A=Mat(L)$, are $D$ and $C$ unique in $D^{-1}AC=\begin{bmatrix}I_r&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

There's a theorem:

> For a matrix A of a linear transformation $L: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, whose rank is $r$, there exists invertible matrices $C_{n\times n}$ and $D_{m\times m}$ for which:
>
> $$D^{-1}AC=\begin{bmatrix}I_r&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

My question is, are these $C$ and $D$ unique or can they be selected (such that they are invertible and the equality above holds)?

---

Solving for $A$ in the above equality produces something called "rank composition" (I don't know what's the correct english term).

Comment: decomposition/factorisation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Rank_factorization

Comment: At the very least, for any $k\ne0$, $D^{-1}AC=(kD^{-1})A(\frac1kC)$, so these matrices are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

These matrices are in general not unique, as can be seen by looking more closely into this theorem.

Let $\{\mathbf v_{r+1},\dots,\mathbf v_n\}$ be a basis for $\ker L$ and extend it to a basis $\{\mathbf v_1,\dots,\mathbf v_r;\mathbf v_{r+1},\dots,\mathbf v_n\}$ for $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\{L\mathbf v_1,\dots,L\mathbf v_r\}$ is a basis for $\operatorname{im}L$; extend it, too to a basis $\{L\mathbf v_1,\dots,L\mathbf v_r;\mathbf w_{r+1},\dots,\mathbf w_n\}$ for $\mathbb R^n$. Relative to this basis, the matrix of $L$ has the desired form, so $D$ and $C$ are really just change-of-basis matrices. These obviously depend on the choice of the two bases.